# JavaScript/Node.JS - compact way of using OR operator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, operators, var

Let's say I have a situation for checking a string. I need to check if it matches `a` or matches `b`. Now, of course, I could just do

```
var firstVar = "a"
var secondVar = "b"
var message = "atest" // note that I might not know what message is. it could be anything. it could be just "test" or just "a"
if ((message === firstVar + "test") || (message === secondVar + "test")) {
   console.log("success!")
}
```

but is there any way to compact this down? Something relating to having a `myVar` being an array with values of `a` and `b` and then checking if `message` **starts with** any value in `myVar`? If anyone has a tip, that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you allowed to use ES6? if so you can use `includes`  otherwise for vanilla ES5 you can make an array and do `indexOf`

Comment: @MikeTung could you link me to or give me an example using `includes`?

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.some()`, `.find()` or `.findIndex()`

Comment: @APixelVisualsI posted examples for you.

Comment: Hey, I guess I have given a bad example, I've edited the original post. Sorry about that

Comment: If `firstVar` and `secondVar` are always one-letter strings, why can't you just do `["a", "b"].includes(message[0])` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an array with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will be the simplest approach:

```
var tests = ["a", "b"];
var message = "atest";
if (tests.some(function(t) { return message === t + "test"; })) {
    console.log("success!")
}
```

If you can use ES6 and need to run this check very often, it might make sense to use

```
const choices = new Set(["a", "b"].map(t => t + "test"));
…
var message = "atest";
if (choices.has(message)) {
    console.log("success!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ES5:

```js
var vars = ["a", "b"].map(function(v) {
  return v + "test";
});
var message = "atest";
if (vars.indexOf(message) > -1) {
   console.log("success!");
}
```

ES6:

```js
var vars = ["a", "b"].map(v => v + "test");
var message = "atest";
if (vars.includes(message)) {
   console.log("success!");
}
```

Comment: i guess i gave a bad example, ive edited the original post. sorry about that

Comment: @APixelVisuals Edited

Comment: nope doesn't seem to be working... it doesn't make it into the if statement

Comment: @APixelVisuals Both work fine in environments that support ES6. The ES6 one does not work in environments that don't support ES6. Did you try clicking the "Run code snippet" button? If yes, did the ES5 one work but the ES6 one didn't?

Comment: @APixelVisuals I just added some semicolons to the end of every line, however, these are not required.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on the array of prefixes and then...:

- If the prefixes are all single characters, just do `messsage[0] === prefix`, which should be the fastest option (no function calls and no string concatenation, just a simple and fast comparison operator.

  ```js
  const prefixes = ["a", "b"];
  const message1 = "atest";
  const message2 = "btest";
  const message3 = "ctest";

  console.log(prefixes.some(prefix => message1[0] === prefix));
  console.log(prefixes.some(prefix => message2[0] === prefix));
  console.log(prefixes.some(prefix => message3[0] === prefix));
  ```
- If the prefixes can have more than one character (also works for a single character), then I would do [`message.indexOf(prefix) === 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

  ```js
  const prefixes = ["at", "bt"];
  const message1 = "atest";
  const message2 = "btest";
  const message3 = "ctest";

  console.log(prefixes.some(prefix => message1.indexOf(prefix) === 0));
  console.log(prefixes.some(prefix => message2.indexOf(prefix) === 0));
  console.log(prefixes.some(prefix => message3.indexOf(prefix) === 0));
  ```

You could also build and use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), which might be faster (depending on the amount and size of the prefixes) if you are going to execute the code multiple times (it will have a penalization the first time you build the RegExp from a string, but then you just reuse that one over and over):

- If the prefixes are a single character:

  ```js
  const prefixes = ["a", "b"];
  const message1 = "atest";
  const message2 = "btest";
  const message3 = "ctest";

  const regexp = new RegExp(`^[${ prefixes.join('') }]`);

  console.log(regexp.test(message1))
  console.log(regexp.test(message2))
  console.log(regexp.test(message3))
  ```
- If the prefixes are multiple characters (also works for a single character):

  ```js
  const prefixes = ["at", "bt"];
  const message1 = "atest";
  const message2 = "btest";
  const message3 = "ctest";

  const regexp = new RegExp(`^(${ prefixes.join('|') })`);

  console.log(regexp.test(message1))
  console.log(regexp.test(message2))
  console.log(regexp.test(message3))
  ```

If you want to check that `message` is actually a combination of any of those prefixes plus something else, let's say `"test"` in your example, then you may want to precompute all the possible options:

- With an Array (or Set as @Bergi suggested) and [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

  ```js
  const prefixes = ["a", "b"];
  const word = "test";
  const options = prefixes.map(prefix => `${ prefix }${ word }`);
  const message1 = "atest";
  const message2 = "btest";
  const message3 = "ctest";

  console.log(options.includes(message1));
  console.log(options.includes(message2));
  console.log(options.includes(message3));

  console.log(options.indexOf(message1) !== -1);
  console.log(options.indexOf(message2) !== -1);
  console.log(options.indexOf(message3) !== -1);
  ```
- With a RegExp and [`RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) or [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

  ```js
  const prefixes = ["a", "b"];
  const word = "test";
  const regexp = new RegExp(`^(${ prefixes.join("|") })${ word }`);
  const message1 = "atest";
  const message2 = "btest";
  const message3 = "ctest";

  console.log(regexp.test(message1));
  console.log(regexp.test(message2));
  console.log(regexp.test(message3));

  console.log(!!message1.match(regexp));
  console.log(!!message2.match(regexp));
  console.log(!!message3.match(regexp));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `includes`; based on your edit:

```
const allowed = ['a','b','ccc'];

if( allowed.includes(`${ message }test`) ) {
    console.log("success!")
}
```

Comment: i guess i gave a bad example, ive edited the original post. sorry about that

Comment: just tried that and it didn't work. It just didn't make it into the if statement

Comment: The question had `message === firstVar + "test"` which means `{ message }test`... Should be correct but there has been so much answers here I doubt it matters ;)

Comment: @Dominik It still does. But your example doesn't evaluate to `true` even if `message` has a value like `"a_hello"`.

Answer (score 0):

Example of using includes and vanilla

**ES6 way**

```
const testArray = [1,2,3];

testArray.includes(1); //returns true
testArray.includes(24); //returns false
```

**ES5 way**

```
var testArray = [1,2,3];
testArray.indexOf(1) // returns 1 since its a member.
testArray.indexOf(43) //returns -1 since it's not a member.
```

Comment: i guess i gave a bad example, ive edited the original post. sorry about that

Comment: all you are doing is just manipulating text, you can write a function to take care of that then use the two examples to solve.